# Can I justify the "center" enviroment to the left, so that it is aligned with "fleqn" equations?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am writing my thesis with the `classicthesis` package. This package uses `fleqn` to justify equations:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath} % Math environments and more by the AMS
```

However, the `center` environment is not to the left. I would like to create a new environment, similar to `center`, in which the text is aligned with the equations.

I considered using the `equation*` enviroment to write the text (i.e., with the `\text` command), however that gives me problems, and I don't think it's a very good solution. More specifically: the endlines must be specified manually (annoying/requires me to decide where its best to break the text), and the alignment is off (right justified?). For example:

[image]

Code here is simply: `\begin{align*} \text{text...}\\ \text{text...}\end{align*}`

Any suggestion how to do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath} % align left eqs
 \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This algorithm never terminates:

\begin{equation*}
    x=x+1
\end{equation*}

And this text is not to the left:

\begin{center}
    I am not well-behaved.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Which results in (note how the text does not align with the equation):

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code and not just images. We have not idea as to what you are actually doing here.

Comment: Why not `\begin{equation*}\text{the text}\end{equation*}`?

Comment: Hi @daleif . Sorry, I'll try to do my best. Unfortunately, I really have no idea where classicthesis does this, so I would have to paste a very large preamble. I'll just paste the code for the equations maybe?

Comment: @egreg I considered that, however, there are two issues with that. The first one is that I would have to break the lines manually (not fatal, but if there was another solution, I'd prefer that). The second one is that there is some vertical spaces between the text and the equations. This vertical space is not there with the ``center'' environment. I like it that way, and if there was a way to align center instead, I'd prefer that one. But if all else fails, I'll do as you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Now you know why using random templates is not always a good idea.

Comment: Remove the blank line between the text and the `equation*`.  That is what causes the extra space between text and a math display and is always wrong.  You might benefit from reading the user guide for `amsmath` (`texdoc amsmath`).

Comment: Thanks for point this out, @barbarabeeton :) This will greatly improve the looks I guess. I still think that the ``\begin{equation*}\text{the text}\end{equation*}`` solution is not ideal, though. I'll update the question accodingly.

Comment: So you want your equations and equation-like text equally offset from the left margin? `\hspace{23mm}\begin{minipage}[t]{34mm}I am well behaved\end{minipage}` good enough?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip I have just tried that. Perhaps I am doing it wrong, but it does not work. On the MWE it doesn't move the text to the left. On my thesis, it makes the text have an endline every three words or so (i.e., very short "lines", poem looking). Perhaps I am missing something? (P.S.: yes, I want them equally offest from the margin, however, I would like them to be exactly offset as fleqn-equations are right now)

Comment: @olinarr: you'll of course need different numbers in there: hspace is the offset, the other number is the width of the box. Our latex experts here might be able to tell you how to adjust these automatically.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip got it. Thank you very much. All of you have been very helpful, and I'll read that manual.

Comment: This sets the formula offset: `\setlength{\mathindent}{23mm}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off, `center` isn't really an environment that should be showing up in your document—it's more something that should be used in building other environments/commands that have semantic meaning.

Now, the next thing is to understand how `center` works. The definition for `center` is¹:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{center}{}{%
   \begin{trivlist}\centering\item\relax
}
{%
   \end{trivlist}%
}
```

What we're doing is creating a single-item `trivlist`²<sup>,</sup>³ and applying the `\centering` definitions to it. `\centering`, in turn is:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\centering{%
  \let\\\@centercr % ❶
  \rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\@flushglue % ❷
  \finalhyphendemerits=\z@ % ❸
  \parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip} % ❹
```

This is fairly straightforward: It makes sure that `\\` starts a new line in the paragraph⁴ ❶, sets the left and right margins to expand equally ❷, makes sure that we don't have the paragraph stretched out an extra line to avoid a hyphenation on the penultimate line⁵ ❸ and finally make sure that we don't get a first-line indent and that there's not extra space on the right for the last line. ❹

So we want to modify this to change the `\leftskip` to no longer be `\@flushglue` but instead follow the `fleqn` indent that you have for paragraphs.⁶ Here's our new definition.

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{somesemanticenvironmentname}{}{%
   \begin{trivlist}
      \let\\\@centercr 
      \rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\mathindent
      \finalhyphendemerits=\z@ 
      \parindent\z@
      \item\relax
}
{%
   \end{trivlist}%
}
```

---

1. This is not the actual definition. I rewrote the code which, in the LaTeX source defines the `center` environment using primitive `\def` commands to use idiomatic LaTeX declarations.
2. `trivlist` is another one of those environments that should never appear directly in a document's code. It's used for building various displayed text environments like `quotation` and `verse` among others. It lets us easily do things like nested `quotation` environments or have these things appear in an `enumerate` with the correctly adjusted margins.
3. The original code uses `\trivlist`…`\endtrivlist` instead of `\begin{trivlist}`…`\end{trivlist}`. In the context of defining an environment, the former syntax is nearly the same since we'll already have the grouping that comes from `\begin{}`…`\end{}` applied. However, with the addition of the hook interfaces for environments that are now part of LaTeX, when defining new code, unless you *explicitly* do not want hooks applied, you should use the environment syntax when wrapping up an environment in another environment definition. It's unlikely anyone is using hooks on `trivlist` but it's probably worth keeping the option open.
4. This is why putting `\centering` in a `p`-column in a `tabular` often causes problems. If you're in the final column of the row, `\\` won't mean end the row, but break a line in the paragraph.
5. This is discussed in the answer to exercise 14.32 in *The TeXbook*.
6. You can find this amount in `fleqn.clo` which identifies it as `\mathindent`.

Comment: This works exactly as intended and your answer is super detailed. Thank you very much!